# Integer axioms question

Tags: integers, axioms

I am stuck on a lecture problem.

Prove that if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x<0$, then $x^3<0$.

I believe that I am supposed to use the integer axioms but am having trouble making the first step or which ones to use.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Note, a negative number times a negative number is positive and a positive number times a negative number is negative. Finally note that $x^3=(x\cdot x)\cdot x$.  If you haven't been given "negative times negative is positive" to work with yet, then prove that first.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the axioms with which you can work; alternatively, it would help if you could edit your post to include those axioms.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
If $x < 0$ then let $x = -y$ with $y > 0$ and now
$$
x^3 = (-y)^3 = (-y) \times (-y) \times (-y) = y^2 \times(-y) = -y^3...
$$

Comment: .. or use $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0$